# MFC TRY CATCH versus C++ try catch for exceptions with MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I used the normal C++ `try` and `catch` for exceptions. Now I want to learn how to use the MFC TRY CATCH. I tried to throw a `int` variable using the C++ syntax with the MFC keywords like this:

```
...
var = 0;
    TRY
    {
        if (var == 0)
        {
            THROW 5;
        }
    }
    CATCH(int a)
    {
      MessageBoxW(L"Blub", L"blub", NULL);
    }
    END_CATCH
```

however it doesn't compile.

Where is the problem? Can someone explain it to me?

Or send a good link where I can learn the MFC TRY CATCH method. I have been unable to find a good explanation.

Comment: Using the MFC macros you can only catch a CException*. The macro is terribly obsolete, don't use it.

Comment: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z28s5c.aspx) is a page where microsoft recommends to convert the MFC macros into the normal c++ try/catch.

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN [Exceptions: Converting from MFC Exception Macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/exceptions-converting-from-mfc-exception-macros?view=vs-2017)

> You probably do not need to convert existing code, although you should
>   be aware of differences between the macro implementations in MFC
>   version 3.0 and the implementations in earlier versions. These
>   differences and subsequent changes in code behavior are discussed in
>   [Exceptions: Changes to Exception Macros in Version 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/exceptions-changes-to-exception-macros-in-version-3-0). The principal
>   advantages of converting are:
>
> - Code that uses the C++ exception-handling keywords compiles to a slightly smaller .EXE or .DLL.
> - The C++ exception-handling keywords are more versatile: They can handle exceptions of any data type that can be copied (int, float,
>     char, and so on), whereas the macros handle exceptions only of class
>     CException and classes derived from it.
>
> The major difference between the macros and the keywords is that code
>   using the macros "automatically" deletes a caught exception when the
>   exception goes out of scope. Code using the keywords does not, so you
>   must explicitly delete a caught exception. For more information, see
>   the article [Exceptions: Catching and Deleting Exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/exceptions-catching-and-deleting-exceptions).

MFC can only catch CException or derived class, use c++ exception if you want to handle other data type.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of source code errors in the code sample you provided.

The MFC TRY CATCH THROW are not C++ keywords but rather are macros that are designed to be used by the C/C++ Preprocessor. So the syntax you need to use with the MFC macros is different than with the C++ keywords. You must use the Preprocessor syntax.

So your source code sample should be written as:

```
int var = 0;

TRY
    if (var == 0) {
        THROW (5);
    }
CATCH(int, a)
END_CATCH
```

However as user Geek above in his posting as well as the comments to your original posting, the MFC TRY CATCH THROW macros are designed to be used with the MFC `CException` class and not like the C++ exceptions which are much more general purpose and much more handy.

With the above, semi-corrected source you will see compiler errors such as:

```
error C2227: left of '->IsKindOf' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
error C2039: 'GetThisClass' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'GetThisClass'
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int *' to 'CException *'
```

These errors are due to not using either a `CException` class or a class derived from `CException`. In general there is a lot of hidden plumbing within the MFC source base which while providing quite a bit of power can also be constraining.

MFC was first released in the early 1990s before the first standard for C++ was released in 1998. So Visual Studio and MFC were on the bleeding edge of the moving target of the first C++ standardization. See [History section of the Wikipedia C++ topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) and [Wikipedia topic Microsoft Visual C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B) as well as [Version history of VC++, MFC and ATL](https://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2015/08/12/version-history-of-vc-mfc-and-atl/). The MFC project at Microsoft had ambitious goals in providing a large and complex framework on top of the Windows API to improve the productivity of Windows application developers.

By changing the `int` in the `CATCH()` to `CException` the source will now compile.

Looking in the MFC include file afx.h you can see where these macros are defined. **Notice the comment that says these are provided only for backward compatibility.**

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Exception macros using try, catch and throw
//  (for backward compatibility to previous versions of MFC)

#define TRY { AFX_EXCEPTION_LINK _afxExceptionLink; try {

#define CATCH(class, e) } catch (class* e) \
    { ASSERT(e->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(class))); \
        _afxExceptionLink.m_pException = e;

#define AND_CATCH(class, e) } catch (class* e) \
    { ASSERT(e->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(class))); \
        _afxExceptionLink.m_pException = e;

#define END_CATCH } }

#define THROW(e) throw e
#define THROW_LAST() (AfxThrowLastCleanup(), throw)

// Advanced macros for smaller code
#define CATCH_ALL(e) } catch (CException* e) \
    { { ASSERT(e->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CException))); \
        _afxExceptionLink.m_pException = e;

#define AND_CATCH_ALL(e) } catch (CException* e) \
    { { ASSERT(e->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CException))); \
        _afxExceptionLink.m_pException = e;

#define END_CATCH_ALL } } }

#define END_TRY } catch (CException* e) \
    { ASSERT(e->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CException))); \
        _afxExceptionLink.m_pException = e; } }
```